# How to change div background color using Javascript and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to change background color of `div` using Ajax and Javascript, but my code is not working:

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.rowcount=function() {
        var exam = new XMLHttpRequest();
        exam.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (exam.readyState == 4) {                             
                var i=document.getElementById("newdata").innerHTML = exam.responseText;
                if(i==1){
                    document.getElementsById("newdata").style.backgroundColor = green;                  
                }

            }
        }
        exam.open("GET", "demo1.php?", true);
        exam.send(null);

</script>
```

Where am I wrong in this code?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `green` is not defined. You can use `"green"` or `#00FF00`.

Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.rowcount=function() {
        var exam = new XMLHttpRequest();
        exam.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (exam.readyState == 4) {


                var i=document.getElementById("newdata").innerHTML = exam.responseText;
             if(i==1){
                  document.getElementsById("newdata").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";

             }

            }
        }
        exam.open("GET", "demo1.php?", true);
        exam.send(null);

    </script>
```

Comment: @satyamsharma Probably because of the `if(i==1)` part

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a bracet and green needs to be a string, so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.rowcount=function(){
    var exam=new XMLHttpRequest();
    exam.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(exam.readyState==4){
        var i=document.getElementById("newdata").innerHTML=exam.responseText;
      }
      if(i==1){
        document.getElementsById("newdata").style.backgroundColor="green";
      }
    }
  }
  exam.open("GET", "demo1.php?", true);
  exam.send();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By Typing green You Pass in a variable. Type "Green" instead